Calculate integral $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }xe^{-nx}\cos xdx$

Calculate integral
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }xe^{-nx}\cos xdx$$

$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }xe^{-nx}\cos xdx=\Re \left \{ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty }xe^{-nx}e^{ix}dx \right \}=\Re \left \{ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\left ( -\frac{xe^{ix-nx}}{n-i}+e^{ix-nx}
 \right )dx \right \}=\Re \left \{ \frac{1}{(n-i)^2} \right \}=\frac{n^2-1}{\left ( n^2+1 \right )^2}$$
$$J=\int xe^{-nx}e^{ix}dx=\begin{vmatrix}
f=x\Rightarrow f'=1\\ 
g'=e^{ix-nx}\Rightarrow g=-\cfrac{e^{ix-nx}}{n-i}
\end{vmatrix}=-\frac{xe^{ix-nx}}{n-i}+\int \frac{e^{ix-nx}}{n-i}dx\overset{ix-nx=t}{=}$$
$$=-\frac{xe^{ix-nx}}{n-i}+\frac{1}{(n-i)^2}\int e^tdt=-\frac{xe^{ix-nx}}{n-i}+e^{ix-nx}$$
This is the most standard way to solve this integral. I want to appeal to integration experts: are there any beautiful solution methods here?
For example, through the Laplace transform or a special function
I'm wondering how such integrals can be solved without taking the imaginary or real part. Yes, and I don’t want to use complex analysis (there’s no beauty there)

I forgot to write, here $n>0$

If you don't want to use complex numbers, then you will need to integrate by parts once to get rid of $x$ and then twice to solve for $\int e^{-nx} \cos{x}$. Don't see an easier way at this moment @Dmitry

We can solve it using the Maclaurin series of the cosine too:
$$\begin{aligned}
\color{red}{\int_0^\infty x e^{-nx}\cos x\,\mathrm dx}&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m}{(2m)!}\int_0^\infty x^{2m+1} e^{-nx}\,\mathrm dx\\
&\hspace{-0.2cm}\overset{z=nx}{=}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m}{n^{2m+2}(2m)!}\int_0^\infty z^{2m+1} e^{-z}\,\mathrm dz\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m\Gamma(2m+2)}{n^{2m+2}(2m)!}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m(2m+1)}{n^{2m+2}}\\
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}}{n^{2m+1}}\\
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}\left[-\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(-\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^m\right]\\
&=-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}\left[\dfrac{n}{n^2+1}\right]\\
&=-\dfrac{(n^2+1)-2n^2}{(n^2+1)^2}\color{red}{=\dfrac{n^2-1}{(n^2+1)^2}},
\end{aligned}$$
where we supposed we could interchange the integral and summation.

A beautiful way through sums

what if $m$ is not an integer?

You can indeed get this looking like a Laplace transform because (gasp) it is one!
The elegant way I went about it was to differentiate under the integral sign: note that
$$\int_0 ^\infty xe^{-nx} \cos x \ dx = -\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \int_0 ^\infty e^{-nx} \cos x \ dx $$
(assuming such an exchange of derivative and integral are valid) and observe the latter can easily be evaluated by integration by parts. Indeed, the result is
$$ -\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} = \frac{n^2 - 1}{(n^2 + 1)^2}.$$
